# Fonts not showing but no errors

Tags: css

I've been making myself a new site over the last couple of days and have had no issue with the fonts when working on my localhost but now when uploading to GitHub they are now not working. All files are there and I have checked that the naming of the files. I have used that Network tab in the developer options of chrome to see if the fonts are loaded

You can view the site here- http://jamiecurd.github.io/
And the rest code is here- https://github.com/jamiecurd/jamiecurd.github.io/tree/master/assets/font/montserrat

This is the loading of the fonts

```html
/*Fonts*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'black';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-Black.ttf') fromat('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Black.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bold';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'extrabold';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'hairline';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-Hairline.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Hairline.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'light';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Light.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'regular';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'semibold';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ultralight';
  src: url('/assets/font/montserrat/Montserrat-UltraLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-UltraLight.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and: 1) Show some code **inline** 2) Explain where you looked for errors (usual spots include JavaScript console and "Net" pane).

Answer (score 0):

your font path is wrong, remove 'assets' in the path of 'truetype' try this

```
src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Black.ttf') fromat('truetype'),
```

also your formate is wrong, try this formate

```html
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Black.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../font/montserrat/Montserrat-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: you need to write src only once not the two times.

Answer (score 0):

The issues regards the src property in your CSS files. Check out the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]
As you can see in the screenshot below, there are errors parsing the value of your "src" (in the file style.css).

1) Fix those following the rules as defined on [W3S site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

2) In your style.css, give proper names to your rules and the font-weight to indicate values such as font "boldness".

3) For the future, I would recommend using the developer tools in your browser to detect such issues.